# After groupby, create a Series from the smallest values in one column corresponding to a value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have some data like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,1,1,2,3,3,2],
                   'y':['n', 'n', 'p', 'p', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'p', 'n'], 
                   'z':[52,75,77,68,92,32,62,70,34]})
```

I'd like to first group it by `x`, and then check if `p` exists in any of the rows of each group, and add another column to the original dataframe (or to the grouped one, and then somehow flatten it back out?) that has either `None` if there were no `p`'s in that group, or the smallest number corresponding to `p` from the `z` column.

So here it'd be:

```
   x  y   z  t
0  1  n  52 68
3  1  p  68 68
4  1  n  92 68

   x  y   z  t
1  2  n  75 None
5  2  n  32 None
8  2  n  34 None

   x  y   z  t
2  3  p  77 70
6  3  n  62 70
7  3  p  70 70
```

or flattened:

```
   x  y   z  t
0  1  n  52 68
3  1  p  68 68
4  1  n  92 68
1  2  n  75 None
5  2  n  32 None
8  2  n  34 None
2  3  p  77 70
6  3  n  62 70
7  3  p  70 70
```

So first we'd do

```
g = df.groupby('x')
```

But then I'm not sure how to proceed.
I'm just having a hard time wrapping my head around it and running into all sorts of pandas error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to filter only the rows in the DataFrame where y is `p`. Then  use [`groupby min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.min.html) to get the minimal z value per group (of remaining rows). Then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to the DataFrame on `x`. `NaN` will automatically be added for any missing values (groups which did not have any values equal to `p`).

```
df = df.join(
    df[df['y'].eq('p')].groupby('x')['z'].min().rename('t'),
    on='x'
)

   x  y   z     t
0  1  n  52  68.0
1  2  n  75   NaN
2  3  p  77  70.0
3  1  p  68  68.0
4  1  n  92  68.0
5  2  n  32   NaN
6  3  n  62  70.0
7  3  p  70  70.0
8  2  n  34   NaN
```

*[`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html) is used here to change the name of the column to the desired before [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)ing back.

---

We can also sort by `x` with [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) if needing the `x` values grouped together:

```
df = df.sort_values('x', ignore_index=True).join(
    df[df['y'].eq('p')].groupby('x')['z'].min().rename('t'), 
    on='x'
)

   x  y   z     t
0  1  n  52  68.0
1  1  p  68  68.0
2  1  n  92  68.0
3  2  n  75   NaN
4  2  n  32   NaN
5  2  n  34   NaN
6  3  p  77  70.0
7  3  n  62  70.0
8  3  p  70  70.0
```

---

Depending on the size of the DataFrame it may be more efficient to select only the `z` column initially with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('x', ignore_index=True).join(
    df.loc[df['y'].eq('p'), 'z'].groupby(df['x']).min().rename('t'),
    on='x'
)

   x  y   z     t
0  1  n  52  68.0
1  1  p  68  68.0
2  1  n  92  68.0
3  2  n  75   NaN
4  2  n  32   NaN
5  2  n  34   NaN
6  3  p  77  70.0
7  3  n  62  70.0
8  3  p  70  70.0
```

Comment: What if i was grouping by multiple columns? I tried .where(df['y'].eq('p').groupby(df[['x', 'w']]) but it's saying ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional. I got this error before and looked into it and it was saying stuff about there being duplicate indices, but I don't think i have any.

Comment: If using that option it would be: `.groupby([df['x'], df['w']])` each Series as a separate item in the list. The first option might be easier since you could just do `.groupby(['x', 'w'])`

Comment: Oh! I was wondering why it wasn't working. Sorry, I meant I need `t` to be the smallest value corresponding to `p`, not just the smallest value in that group. I updated the table in my question so it's more clear.

Comment: @Raksha should be fixed now. This way we only consider `z` values where y is equal to `p` not all the values within the group.

Comment: Hell yeah (⌐▨_▨) b

Answer (score 2):

@HenryEcker covered all the nice intuitive solutions. This one's just for fun.

The basic idea is filter the rows where "y" is 'p' and among these rows find the minimum value of "z" for each "x". Then map it back to "x":

```
df['t'] = df['x'].map(df[df['y'].eq('p')].groupby('x')['z'].min())
df = df.sort_values(by='x')
```

An alternative method using `eq` + `where`. The basic idea is to mask the "z" values corresponding to non-"p"  values in column "y"; then `groupby` "x" and transform the minimum "z":

```
df['t'] = df['z'].where(df['y'].eq('p')).groupby(df['x']).transform('min')
```

Output:

```
   x  y   z     t
0  1  n  52  68.0
3  1  p  68  68.0
4  1  n  92  68.0
1  2  n  75   NaN
5  2  n  32   NaN
8  2  n  34   NaN
2  3  p  77  70.0
6  3  n  62  70.0
7  3  p  70  70.0
```

Comment: You guys are awesome :) Sorry, i realized the question wasn't super clear. I updated it. I meant for `t` to have the smallest value corresponding to `p`, not just the smallest value in that group.

Comment: @Raksha you probably already got a working solution from HenryEcker but I have updated my answer as well if you're interested.